# DNG Compatibility in Adobe Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, raw, file-format, compatibility, dng

In Adobe Lightroom CC 2015.3, Preferences -> File Handling -> Compatibility, I have "Camera Raw 7.1 and later" selected. After importing RAW files, for example a few Sony's ARW RAW files, via Import -> Copy as DNG, I end up with files that show below in Metadata -> DNG panel:

- DNG Version 1.4
- DNG Compatibility 1.3
- Compatibility Lightroom 2.4

How do I obtain DNG files with the latest compatibility? Are there any downsides that my RAW files seem to be "older"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not "older". They are Version 1.4 as you can see. It is the latest DNG version as for now. "DNG Compatibility" means that these files will be readable by older software that can read DNG 1.3 (but can not read DNG 1.4).

Comment: Thanks, it finally makes sense. I think the Preferences mention of Camera Raw with a much higher version number confused me. I was also able to find the latest 1.4 specs (October 2012) for anyone interested: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/digital-negative.html.